# Mouse hover event in Getorgchart

Tags: javascript, orgchart, getorgchart

Mouse hover event in Getorgchart view. how to write the mouse hover event and mouse out event in Getorgchart view. Shall I get the org chart element details while doing mouse hove/leave?

Answer (score 1):

You can attach mouseover event to each node. Here is an example

```
var orgchart = new getOrgChart(document.getElementById("people"), {
    updatedEvent: mouseoverListener,
    dataSource: [
        { id: 1, parentId: null, Name: "Amber McKenzie" },
        { id: 2, parentId: 1, Name: "Ava Field" },
        { id: 3, parentId: 1, Name: "Evie Johnson" }]
});

function mouseoverListener() {
    var boxes = document.querySelectorAll("[data-node-id]");
    for (i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
        boxes[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function () { alert("hovered node ID is " + this.getAttribute("data-node-id")) });
    }
}

mouseoverListener();
```

Comment: Is it possible to show buttons in a specific box using this method, 
like when I hover over a box that button will show and we can click on it also, show
only on that box and not others, @balkanGraph

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Are you using BALKAN OrgChartJS https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS, note that GetOrgChart library is no longer supported